# MuleSoft Anypoint Studio- DataSense not working for Salesforce Connector

Tags: mule, datamapper, mule-studio

I have a problem with Datasense for querying in Salesforce connector. By clicking on 'Query Builder' for 'Datasense Query Language', the popup window doesn't have the required data in the left/right panel. Also by clicking on add filter respective dropdown has no value to apply the filter.

Below is the screenshot for reference:

[image]

**Note:** I have checked the Datasense option in connector configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was somewhere related to the studio itself. I have replaced the studio to the new version and everything is working fine. I know it's a weird, but it has solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, resolved it by clearing the project cache. You need to do the following:

- Check your sfdc config, make sure you are successfully able to
  connect to Salesforce.
- Close your project then clear the contents of:

  > Workspace\MuleProject\ .studio\caches

.

Comment: sfdc config is correct and the hence Test Connection succeds. I have cleared the cache on specified location but still no luck!

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be releated to the salesforce account itself. I have tried using another account and it worked properly.

I will look into this problem.

Agustin Celentano

Comment: Thanks for your valuable....................................................................... Hmm.. that sounds a different scenario. But this doesn't solved my problem. However by replacing my anypoint studio with a new one(same version) worked for me. I don't know what the problem was but this has solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Tried other answers suggested here but did not work for me. Answer which worked for me is in the following link

http://forums.mulesoft.com/questions/884/module-4-salesforce-query-builder-doesnt-display-any-table-and-field-information-but-test-connection-is-successful.html